# How can I type a table here?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Declension tables are quite useful here. How can I type them? Is there non-painful way to type them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [duplicate on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/288176) says it's not possible, not in the Markdown dialect SE uses, but some of the answers offer workarounds, like this one from the 1960s: [ASCII art tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139013/288176).